# Automate Conditional Template used in Word MailMerge

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, templates, microsoft-word-2003

I have four different Word 2003 documents set up, all using the same Excel data source, but the documents have different logos, text, terms and columnar content layouts.

Currently

```
remLetter1.doc  
remLetter2.doc  
remLetter_c1.doc  
remLetter_c2.doc
```

each gets opened, setup and run individually.

There must be a simple way to  automate the template used for each record, rather than opening each document, setting up the recipient list, and merging four times. It works the way it is now, but really seems like it could be a shorter task.

What would be a way to do this?

Comment: perhaps. This will require vba code so I thought this more likely to garner assistance here. how do you move a question if that is deemed appropriate?

Comment: you can flag to have your own post closed or migrated by a moderator. MailMerge wouldn't require VBA - it's extremely well-versed in conditional formatting without any code-behind (i.e. use fields in the doc itself).

Comment: what I am trying to do goes beyond conditional usage of data in merge fields and their formatting. I need to specify a whole document template conditionally.

Comment: Why can't you setup the mail merge via VBA and choose the template there at the same time?